# rails search by string RecordNotFound error Couldn't find all Items with 'id'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to find all items where has Item name has my substring.

This is my item.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end

end
```

This is my search function in controller:

```
def search 
  @items=Item.search(params[:word])
end
```

And I get this error:
Couldn't find all Items with 'id': (all, {:conditions=>["name LIKE ?", "%xxx%"]}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)

```
Extracted source (around line #4):

    def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
```

[image]

What do I do?

Comment: and also I have at least one item with name xxx in my database!

Comment: Make sure you're passing the proper params. In your search function, what do you get when you say `p params.inspect`?

Comment: Where should I write this params.inspect?

Comment: in your controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `find(:all, :conditions => '...')` syntax was removed in rails 4.1. You can add it back with the [activerecord-deprecated_finders](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders#active-record-deprecated-finders) although this is not going to be updated for rails 5 (at least not by the rails team).

The modern way of expressing this would be

```
where("name like ?", "%#{search}%")
```

Comment: cool it works! 2 more questions: 1)what about sql injections?

Comment: 2) what if I don't find anything how to prevent an exeption?

Comment: Separate questions should be exactly that: questions, not comments (although do check before asking as these have surely been asked before).